# ServiceStack Todo Rest Api with Crud operations - How to override Get, Post.. etc methods?

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

These are my first steps in ServiceStack. I am a total noob.

I created simple Todo Rest Api with MySql Db connection. I am trying to Get all the incoming Todos based on date (greater than or equal given date).

What I have is simple Get method where DateTo paramater is passed.
[image]
It works only if the date is equal to the existing, example :
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to modyfy the method that I can specyfy that the date is not equal but should be great than or equal.

How can I modify Post, Get, Update.. methods?

Types.cs

```
using System;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;

namespace ToDoApp.ServiceModel.Types
{
    public class Todo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Percentage { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
        public int Done { get; set; }
    }

}
```

GetIncomingTodo.cs

```
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using ToDoApp.ServiceModel.Types;

namespace ToDoApp.ServiceModel
{
    [Route("/todo/incoming", "GET")]
    [Route("/todo/incoming/{DateTo}", "GET")]
    public class GetIncomingTodo
        : QueryDb<Todo>, IReturn<QueryResponse<Todo>>, IGet
    {
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    }

}
```

MyServices.cs

```
using ServiceStack;
using ToDoApp.ServiceModel;
using ToDoApp.ServiceModel.Types;

namespace ToDoApp.ServiceInterface;

public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(Test request)
    {
        return new TestResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Title}!" };
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());

app.Run();
```

Configure.AppHost.cs

```
using Funq;
using ServiceStack;
using ToDoApp.ServiceInterface;

[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(ToDoApp.AppHost))]

namespace ToDoApp;

public class AppHost : AppHostBase, IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) => builder
        .ConfigureServices(services => {
            // Configure ASP.NET Core IOC Dependencies
        });

    public AppHost() : base("ToDoApp", typeof(MyServices).Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        // Configure ServiceStack only IOC, Config & Plugins
        SetConfig(new HostConfig {
            UseSameSiteCookies = true,
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Parameters in a URL query is after the question mark at end of URL.  The URL is a string so when querying a database you have to query using a parameter that is a DateTime object so the string date has to be converted to a DateTime object.

Comment: You may need to use the _annotation_ for your model (_DTO_) class, on the `DateTo`  property,  `[QueryDbField(Operand = ">=")]` to make your query to look for greater than or equal to, see [documentation](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#customizable-adhoc-queries)

Comment: That's exactly what Im looking for @Anand Sowmithiran, but where to put this ```[QueryDbField(Operand = ">=")]``` code exactly in which class? It is for me like discovering fire, really first steps. I am using default methods in my code right? Cause for me it's like I haven't done almost anything and everything works. Thank you for that comment, I didn't even know that something like this existed

Comment: `Implicit conventions` do seem to already support several variations like greater than, greater than or equal to , and so on, see the doc [page](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#implicit-conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v6 Release Notes has [TODO MVC examples](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v6#todos-mvc) for all its [jamstacks.net](https://jamstacks.net) templates whose C# & UI source code is linked on each of its pages:

- https://vue-ssg.jamstacks.net/todomvc
- https://blazor-wasm.jamstacks.net/todomvc
- https://nextjs.jamstacks.net/todomvc

It makes use of the new [InMemory AutoQuery PocoDataSource](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v6#new-queryable-pocodatasource) which lets you query each property with AutoQuery's [Implicit Conventions](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#implicit-conventions):

- [/api/QueryTodos?Id>=1](https://blazor-wasm-api.jamstacks.net/api/QueryTodos?Id%3E=1)
- [/api/QueryTodos?TextContains=Blazor](https://blazor-wasm-api.jamstacks.net/api/QueryTodos?TextContains=Blazor)
- [/api/QueryTodos?IsFinished=false](https://blazor-wasm-api.jamstacks.net/api/QueryTodos?IsFinished=false)

If your AutoQuery API Data Model had a `DateTo` property then you would be able to perform a **"Greater than or equal to"** query with any of:

```
 - /todos?DateTo>=2022-01-01
 - /todos?DateToOnOrAfter=2022-01-01
 - /todos?DateToFrom=2022-01-01
 - /todos?FromDateTo=2022-01-01
 - /todos?DateToSince=2022-01-01
 - /todos?DateToGreaterThanOrEqualTo=2022-01-01
```

etc.